# What's the meaning of 90-plus?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What's the meaning of 90-plus? More than 90? If so, please tell me more ways to say "more than 90". Thank you!

Comment: "90 plus" means an amount greater than or equal to 90.  One would expect that the number indicated is somewhere close to 90.  You would not generally hear somebody saying 90 plus when the amount is 1000.  I don't know of any other means of expressing this idea, so I'll leave a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: It sounds like yet another pension-deferring work-extending plan by the British Government of whichever day. A test to decide on your future opportunities.

Answer (score 4):

*#-plus* is used typically when quantifying something with a rough estimate. Typically, when using the phrase, the implication is that there are *at least* that many. Using your example, if someone told you there were *90-plus* grapefruits, you could likely count on there being at least 90, plus a little more.

Other examples of this might include sports, such as American football, where a player may have run for *100-plus* yards. It is not an accurate way of presenting statistics at all, rather more conversational.

Other ways of saying "more than 90" (besides the obvious) include *over 90* and *greater than 90*.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a difference in saying "90 plus" and "more than 90".

In most cases "more than 90" infers that the speaker knows the actual number.  90 would then be the minimum number.  The speaker might say this to provide a brief estimate, to point out the low end of a spectrum, or maybe as some sort of negotiation ploy (sure there are other reasons).

Then I would infer that "90  plus" means that the speaker is unsure of the actual number but knows that it is more than 90.  For instance if you were buying a shirt that was $89.99 in the US you might describe the price as 90 plus.  $89.99 plus tax and we aren't sure what the after tax price would be.  Also if you are watching a football game and someone asks you how many yards a player has...  Well you know he had 90 yards at least 10 minutes ago in the game, so you say "90 plus", because you don't really know beyond 90.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means more than (greater than) 90.

Example usages:

> - There are 90 plus dogs in that basket.
> - It'll cost 90 plus dollars to buy that dog.
> - The dog is 90 plus years old.